# coordinate regex not match if value more than 99

Tags: regex

I have a regex like this :

```
(-?\d{1,2}\.\dE-\d+|-?\d{1,2}\.?\d*)\s(-?\d{1,2}\.\dE-\d+|-?\d{1,2}\.?\d*)\s?0?\s?0?,?
```

and i test with

```
99.972534 -6.147714,
```

that's match all of the test. but when i use

```
100.972534 -6.147714,
```

all match but '1' of 100, the result like this :

```
00.972534 -6.147714,
```

please help me update this regex so can match the test

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(-?\d{1,2}\.\dE-\d+|-?\d{1,3}\.?\d*)\s(-?\d{1,2}\.\dE-\d+|-?\d{1,2}\.?\d*)\s?0?\s?0?,?
                           ^
```

Try this.See demo.It was accepting only `2` digits.Made it to accept `3`.

http://regex101.com/r/hQ9xT1/30

Answer (score 1):

Your regex specifies 1 or 2 leading digits via `\d{1,2}`, but `100` has *3* digits.

Change all occurrences of `\d{1,2}` to `\d{1,3}`

Answer (score 1):

At the beginning of your regex, you have "\d{1,2}", which matches from 1 to up to 2 digits only. So, you probably want to change that to "\d+" (1 or more times) or "\d{1,3}" (in case you want to match from 1 to up to 3 digits). This is all explain on the API page of the Pattern class: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html